# Pro Audio Live Sound equipment vs Pro Audio DJ equipment

Tags: discussion

It is known and given that questions about Pro Audio Live sound reinforcement equipment, PA systems are on-topic on this site.

However, what is the status of DJ equipment. 
This is a Pro Audio sound reinforcement, but is it on or off topic here.

Example question: [Pioneer RX2 how to power off safely](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44830/pioneer-rx2-how-to-power-off-safely)

This question was flagged close with reason of being off topic.

**Are DJ equipment questions off topic ?** And if so, what is the reasoning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on which DJ equipment.  Mixers and speakers would be, but things like lighting consoles and probably turn tables would not fall within scope.  Turn tables is a tricky one since it's some parts sound design and some parts instrument, but I kind of feel like it's more on the instrument side.  I guess the context of what someone is trying to do with turn tables might be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 1):

Sound Design questions are on topic. If your sound design questions are related to DJ equipment then they may be on topic, but there will also be many DJ equipment questions that are off topic.

So don't think of it as an "are DJ equipment questions off topic" - instead, focus on making sure your question is on topic as per [our site scope.](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s a good idea to judge DJ questions on a case-by-case basis, and edit the question to remove overly DJ-specific bits.